# Resultado de um SELECT para usar em outro SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql

Sei que o título é meio confuso, mas irei explicar aqui:

Tenho um select, que exibe para mim as lojas que tenham uma promoção (**CONSULTA 1**):

```
SELECT * FROM empresas INNER JOIN promocoes ON empresas.id = promocoes.id_empresa WHERE promocoes.ativo = 'sim' GROUP BY empresas.nome_fantasia
```

No meu segundo select, tenho a seguinte consulta (**CONSULTA 2**):

```
SELECT *, empresas.id AS id_emp, FROM empresas LEFT OUTER JOIN promocoes ON promocoes.id_empresa = empresas.id WHERE promocoes.id_empresa IS NULL OR promocoes.ativo = 'nao' GROUP BY empresas.nome_fantasia
```

Funciona perfeitamente, mas se uma empresa tiver 2 promoções, e desativar uma promoção dela no painel de controle, a empresa aparece 2 vezes:

- na primeira consulta, pois tem uma promoção ativa
- na segunda consulta, pois tem uma promoção inativa.

Então, queria saber: como fazer com que uma empresa, que tenha uma promoção ativa (aparece na CONSULTA 1), não apareça na CONSULTA 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu tentaria usar `NOT EXISTS`.
Sem os comandos para criar e popular minimamente as tabelas, tentei escrever de cabeça como ficaria tal consulta. É mais ou menos isso:

```
SELECT DISTINCT empresas.nome_fantasia
FROM empresas
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM promocoes WHERE empresas.id = promocoes.id_empresa AND promocoes.ativo = 'sim')
```